# Can't get Flickity slider to appear in between two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So here's my culprit website: http://imranahmed.io/

For some reason, I can't get the "About Me" `<div>` to appear directly below my `flickity slider` - instead the About Me page overlaps the slider and the slider disappears into the background.

Here's an example which shows the "About Me" page covering the image:

[image: Exhibit A]

I've tried setting the css of the carousel to `display:inside-block` but that hasn't made any difference so I'm very confused as to how I should proceed. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
--- 
layout: default 
title: index 
permalink: / 
---

<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link href="/static/css/flickity.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.flickity-slider').flickity({
            cellAlign: 'left',
            contain: true,
            autoPlay: true,
            pageDots: false,
            pauseAutoPlayOnHover: false
        });
        $(".nav navbar-nav navbar-right").addClass("active");
    });
</script>

<div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top" id="i18_title"><span data-i18n="website.title">{{ site.title }}</span></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="i18_navbar">
                    {% for section in site.data.landing %}
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#{{ section.id }}">
                            <span data-i18n="{{ section.i18n }}">{{ section.name }}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="flickity-slider">
    {% for slider in site.data.slider %}
    <div class="carousel-cell"><img class="carousel-image" src="{{ slider.img | prepend: site.baseurl }}" alt=""></div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<div>
{% for section in site.data.landing %}
    {% assign loopindex = forloop.index | modulo: 2 %}
    <section id="{{ section.id }}" class="features {% if loopindex != 1 %} gray-section {% endif %} {{ section.css }}" style="margin-top: 0px;">
        {% include sections/{{section.tpl}} %}
    </section>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

The `about.html` page is simple another div class called "container"

And here is the corresponding CSS:

```
.landing-page .flickity-slider{
    height: 30%;
}
.landing-page .carousel-cell{
    width: 100%; /* full width */
    height: 470px; /* height of carousel */
    max-height: 470px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

}
.landing-page .carousel-image{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-width: 100%
    max-height: 30%
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

I'm very new to CSS so I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong - help and advice would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: you're getting a script error out of scroll.js btw.

Comment: Sorry yep, I had accidentally loaded jquery twice - let me just resolve that! I think the issue still remains unfortunately :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `position:absolute` on div with `class=flickity-slider`, and the subsequent "about me" div will "clear" correctly.

[image]

[more info](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/):

> The trade-off, and most important thing to remember, about absolute
>   positioning is that these elements are removed from the flow of
>   elements on the page. An element with this type of positioning is not
>   affected by other elements and it doesn't affect other elements. This
>   is a serious thing to consider every time you use absolute
>   positioning. It's overuse or improper use can limit the flexibility of
>   your site.

Comment: Hi, @sweaver2112, thanks for your answer! Which position:absolute are you referring to (in my code)? I can't see where I've giving the `flickity-slider` div `position:absolute`. Is this the position absolute on the `carousel-image class ` I've made?

Comment: yes, that's what i removed (you can test it easily using chrome dev tools elements tab and uncheck that rule), and it worked.

Comment: Hmm, that isn't doing anything on my end (and in fact it removes the alignment of the images inside the <img> object)

I'm sorry if this is a really simple fix - I'm very new to web-dev!

Comment: Ahhhh okay! I can see what you're talking about now!! I never knew Chrome had these sort of tools! I think this information is defined in the default flickity.css file - so I have to find a way of removing it!

Comment: Resolved! Thanks! Now to solve the issue of overlapping images urghh! Thanks for your help @sweaver2112

Answer (score 1):

Change this part of code

```
<div class="flickity-slider">
{% for slider in site.data.slider %}
<div class="carousel-cell"><img class="carousel-image" src="{{ slider.img | prepend: site.baseurl }}" alt=""></div>
{% endfor %}
```

to

```
<div class="carousel">
    {% for slider in site.data.slider %}
    <div class="carousel-cell"><img class="carousel-image" src="{{ slider.img | prepend: site.baseurl }}" alt=""></div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The `flickity-slider` class is "internal" class of `flickity` that has some default styling. This is the reason why About me section is on the top of flickity slider.

Please remember that you have to change class also in JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').flickity({
        cellAlign: 'left',
        contain: true,
        autoPlay: true,
        pageDots: false,
        pauseAutoPlayOnHover: false
    });
    $(".nav navbar-nav navbar-right").addClass("active");
});
```

Just in case, if you want define height of carousel, you can do it like in the example in official documentation: http://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#setgallerysize

Comment: I agree, there end up being two classes 'flickety-slider' - my solution illustrates that, but better to just use your own class and not change the css :)